# Because examplecode depends on audioplayers ^0.16.2 which depends on path_provider ^1.6.22, path_provider ^1.6.22 is required

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello friends I am using path provider plugin in application now also I want add audio player plugin when ever I tried install audio packages in my application it show me this error please help me what issue why unable install audio packages in my application if used path provider package path provider have any issue with audio plugin?

```
Because examplecode depends on audioplayers ^0.16.2 which depends on path_provider ^1.6.22, path_provider ^1.6.22 is required.
So, because examplecode depends on path_provider ^0.4.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because examplecode depends on path_provider ^0.4.1, version solving failed.)
```

here is my packages

```
name: examplecode
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  audioplayers: ^0.16.2
  http: "0.11.3+17"
  path_provider: ^0.4.1
  archive: ^2.0.8
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+2



  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

but your answer is not actually the way to do it.

This problem in general is a problem of packages being in conflict. to solve this for any packages that are not compatible with each other is simple

1. in pubspec.yaml instead of writing version numbers for those conflicting packages, instead replace the version with 'any'.

E.G
instead of

```
 audioplayers: ^0.13.6
```

write this:

```
 audioplayers: any
```

2. than run 'flutter pub get' in terminal.
3. than the problem should be solved, however dont go leaving them on 'any', thats very bad practice. so go to your pubspec.lock file and look for those packages, you will see that flutter have chosen versions for them automatically and those versions are what flutter found them both being compatible with. take those versions and replace the 'any' version back to those new version numbers given by pub.

take care

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question actually audio player have its own path provider by default so we don't need to using path provider solve my problem